# Https: Weak Connection

Tags: http, ssl, https

I have a website on which users can write blog posts. For adding Images users can add the URL of an Image & image will be shown on their blog post.

But problem is that if a user inserts link of an image starting with `http://` such as `http://example.com/flower.jpg`, browser shows a warning saying,

```
Your Connection to this site is not Fully Secure.

Attackers might be able to see the images you are looking at
& trick you by modifying them
```

I was wondering how can we force the browser to use the `https://` version of site only from which image is being inserted to prevent this issue?

Or is there any other solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to download the image and serve it from your own domain.
This also avoids issues due to hotlinking.

Alternatively you can try to replace `http` with `https` but there is no guarantee that the target website has a valid certificate or even a webserver listening there.

Comment: Sir, what about first uploading the image to a trusted image hosting company & then taking it from there?

Comment: That's pretty much the first part of my answer.

Comment: Sir, I've just noticed that stackoverflow does the same exact thing in case we want to add an image via it's link. I was wondering is there any documentation or something to help me do this? Right now I have no idea how will I do this?